# Why do I lose value by renaming the key of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, key, key-value

by renaming the key of an object I lose the value. How can I make sure that only the key is changed and the value remains?

this is my object

```js
const items = {
  "brand": "losee",
  "target": "brand",
  "item": {
    "name": null,
    "fabric": null,
    "country": "CH",
    "fit": "regular"
  }
}

// for renaming the key I use this method

delete Object.assign(items, { prototype: items.item.fit }).fit;

console.log(items)
```

and after this method my object looks like this

```
{
  "brand": "losee",
  "target": "brand",
  "item": {
    "name": null,
    "fabric": null,
    "country": "CH",
    "prototype": null
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
thank you all

Comment: The output in the question is wrong. `Object.assign` adds a `prototype` key to the main `items` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning to `items.item`

```js
const items = {
  "brand": "losee",
  "target": "brand",
  "item": {
    "name": null,
    "fabric": null,
    "country": "CH",
    "fit": "regular"
  }
}

delete Object.assign(items.item, { prototype: items.item.fit }).fit

console.log(items)
```